# sort elements alphabetically with duplicates based on children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to sort my divs inside xmen alphabetically based on the inner 2nd divs paragraph element. This is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#xmen > .g > div:nth-of-type(2) > p').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.textContent < b.textContent) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }).appendTo('#xmen');
});
```

with the html of

```
<div id="xmen">
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>marvel vs capcom</p></div>
    <div><p>CCC</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>matrix</p></div>
    <div><p>Neo</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>Neo Geo</p></div>
    <div><p>Neo</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>Neo Geo</p></div>
    <div><p>Neo</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>Neo Geo</p></div>
    <div><p>Neo</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>Neo Geo</p></div>
    <div><p>Neo</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>Neo Geo</p></div>
    <div><p>Neo</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>Matrix</p></div>
    <div><p>Smith</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>JSON</p></div>
    <div><p>Neo</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I'm not doing it correctly because it seems to be taking it out of the divs and shooting it to the bottom of the last div instead of organizing each g class div alphabetically. What could be the issue? I seem to have issues with the duplicates being sorted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the same thing Gary S posted, but with jquery selectors to find the child `p` element:

```
$('#xmen > .g').sort(function(ga, gb) {
    var a = $(ga).find('div:nth-of-type(2) > p');
    var b = $(gb).find('div:nth-of-type(2) > p');
    if (a.text() < b.text()) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }).appendTo('#xmen');
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jac7040k/2/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will do what you were asking for:

```js
$(function() {

    // First get the entire 'x-men' div
    var movieContainer = $('#xmen');

    // Store all "g" divs
    var movieDivs =movieContainer.find('.g');

    // Then sort them based on the text content of the last element
    movieDivs.sort(function(a, b) {

        var result = a.lastChild.previousSibling.textContent < b.lastChild.previousSibling.textContent;

     if (result === true) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    });
  // Finally, overwrite the previous HTML of the 'x-men' div
  // with the new sorted content (I also changed the text color
  // to make it easier to differentiate)
  movieDivs.find('p:last').css('color', 'orange');
    movieContainer.html(movieDivs);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xmen">
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>marvel vs capcom</p></div>
    <div><p>CCC</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>matrix</p></div>
    <div><p>Neo</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>matrix</p></div>
    <div><p>Morpheus</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>matrix</p></div>
    <div><p>Trinity</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>Neo Geo</p></div>
    <div><p>Neo</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>X Men</p></div>
    <div><p>Apocalypse</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>Neo Geo</p></div>
    <div><p>Neo</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>Matrix</p></div>
    <div><p>Smith</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g'>
    <div><p>JSON</p></div>
    <div><p>Neo</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The unsorted children already exists in `#xmen` and you add the sorted one to it again. you must somehow remove the old ones and add the sorted ones:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var temp = $('<div/>');
      $('#xmen > .g > div:nth-of-type(2) > p').sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.textContent < b.textContent) {
          return -1;
        } else {
          return 1;
        }
      }).appendTo(temp);
    $('#xmen').html(temp.html());

});
```

And also in your code you should change `.appendTo('#xmen');` to `.appendTo($('#xmen'));`

See the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k6qg3zb7/)

Comment: I added a demo please have a look at it

Comment: Got it, the demo is malfunctioning though with var temp = $('<div/>'); instead of var temp = $('</div>');

Comment: well now is it what you wanted?